# ¿Como agregar contenido de dos listas como columnas al final de un DataFrame de Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hola necesito agregar columnas a la derecha de un DataFrame aqui mi codigo

```
from itertools import combinations as com

res1 =[] 
res2 =[] 
res3 =[] 

for c in com(list_1, 5):

    res1.append (c)    
   

for c in com(list_2, 5):

    res2.append (c)


for c in com(list_3, 5):

    res3.append (c)


df = pd.DataFrame(res1)   

df.index= [_ for _ in range(1,len(df)+1)]

df.to_csv('data.csv', header=None , sep=' ', index=None)
```

El resultado del archivo csv es este

```
1  17 24 90 28 41 
2  17 24 90 28 21 
3  17 24 90 28 39 
4  17 24 90 28 75 
5  17 24 90 28 77 
6  17 24 90 28 19 
7  17 24 90 41 21 
8  17 24 90 41 39 
9  17 24 90 41 75 
10  17 24 90 41 77
```

Hasta ahi perfecto pero quiero agregar a la derecha el contenido de list2 y list3 lo que quedaría 10 columnas mas por que cada lista tiene 5 tambien al igual que list1.

Intente esto **df = pd.DataFrame(res1, res2, res3)** pero no me funciona me da un error que desconozco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente haría el merge de las combinaciones antes de crear el DataFrame, pero si lo quieres hacer así debes usar [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat):

```
from itertools import combinations as com
import pandas as pd

res1 = []
res2 = []
res3 = []

for c in com(list_1, 5):
    res1.append(c)

for c in com(list_2, 5):
    res2.append(c)

for c in com(list_3, 5):
    res3.append(c)

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(res1), pd.DataFrame(res2), pd.DataFrame(res3)], axis=1, join="inner")

df.index = [_ for _ in range(1, len(df) + 1)]

df.to_csv('data.csv', header=False, sep=' ', index=False)
```

---

Para preparar la lista antes de generar el DataFrame puedes probar con:

```
data = [v + res2[i] + res3[i] for i, v in enumerate(res1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Obviamente esto sólo funciona si las listas originales tienen el mismo tamaño.

Comment: Pense en realizarlo antes y desde luego hice varios intentos pero no supe como hacerlo. Aun no estoy muy ducho en todas las funciones de que dispongo en Python soy medio nuevo en esto. Como se podria hacer antes ?

Comment: Añado una posible alternativa en mi respuesta